# Scala Date Format issue

Tags: java, scala, scala-2.8

I have code snippet which is giving different output in scala and java. I want the same output as in Java, any one please guide.

Output in Java: `2012-12-13T10:36:38`
Output in Scala: `2012-12-13T10:35:38.000+04:00`

```
/**
 * Convert the datetime to XMLGregorianCalendar datetime format.
 * <br><h6>Example Date format You have to Give is : </h6>
 * new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())) 
 * <br>1900-01-01T00:00:00
 */
public static XMLGregorianCalendar stringToXMLGregorianCalendar(String datetime) throws Exception {

    try {
        if(datetime == null || "".equals(datetime))
            return null;
        GregorianCalendar gc = (GregorianCalendar) GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        gc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(datetime));
        return DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        logger.error(e.fillInStackTrace());
        throw new Exception(e.fillInStackTrace());
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your Scala code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem please find the solution below.

I have set the timezone and millisecond to undefined in the above code.

`xgc.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)`
`xgc.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)`

```
    try {
        if (datetime == null || "".equals(datetime))
            return null
        val gc = new GregorianCalendar()
        gc.setTime(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(datetime))
        val xgc = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gc)
        xgc.setMillisecond(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)
        xgc.setTimezone(DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED)
        return xgc
    } catch {
        case e: DatatypeConfigurationException => logger.error(e.fillInStackTrace()); throw new Exception(e.fillInStackTrace())
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should change a timezone

```
val d = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTime())
val gc: java.util.GregorianCalendar = classOf[java.util.GregorianCalendar].newInstance().asInstanceOf[java.util.GregorianCalendar];     gc.setTime(new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(d));
gc.getTime
gc.getTimeZone
```

Result:

```
res6: java.util.Date = Thu Dec 13 17:21:50 GMT+02:00 2012
res7: java.util.TimeZone = sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+02:00",offset=7200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the answer but i am expecting a specific result which i have to pass to some other classes, how ever you can see the answer below how i have handled.